# drawText on QGraphicsView::drawForeground

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qpainter, qfontmetrics

My code is below.

```
void MyView::drawForeground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    Q_UNUSED(rect);

    painter->save();

    QRectF rt = viewport()->rect();
    painter->setWorldMatrixEnabled(false);

    QString strInfo = "test12345";

    painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
    painter->setPen(Qt::white);

    painter->setFont(QFont("Segoe UI", 200, QFont::Bold));

    QFontMetrics fm(painter->font());
    int fmWidth = fm.width(strInfo, strInfo.length());
    int fmHeight = fm.height();

    painter->drawRect(rt);
    painter->drawText(10, 10, fmWidth, fmHeight, Qt::AlignCenter, strInfo);
    painter->drawRect(10, 10, fmWidth, fmHeight);
    painter->setWorldMatrixEnabled(true);
    painter->restore();
}
```

result image

[image]

QfontMetrics does not seem to return the correct size.
What's wrong with my code?

I do not know what to do anymore.

QFontMetrics returns the size of the white rectangle of the attached image, but the actual Text is drawn small.

Comment: It works for me correctly: https://imgur.com/a/vsNDQqO with Qt 5.11.1

Comment: I can not see what went wrong. Are there any other elements related to QPainter :: drawText?

Comment: As I said I used your code and did not find any problem, maybe some part that does not show your code generates that problem, could share your entire project through github or similar

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I need to debug again one by one.

Comment: I removed my scene and replaced it with the default QGraphicsScene. It has exactly. Perhaps it is affected by the size of the scene.
remove "fitInView", QFontMetrics returns the correct value.

Comment: If you provide a decent [mcve] you could try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of `QPainter::setWorldMatrixEnabled(false)`, `QPainter::drawText()` behaves as a scene coordinate.